# Scope settings - what does "list" type returns?

Tags: application-development, scopes

i am trying to get the string selected from a list (defined in the settings.ini with name [listname]) using this code:

```
unity::scopes::VariantMap config = settings();
std::string selected_string = config["listname"].get_string();
```

However it says this:

```
ScopeBase::run(): unity::LogicException: Variant does not contain a string value:
boost::bad_get: failed value get using boost::get
```

What does the Variant variable contain? How can i retrieve the selected entry?

Answer (score 3):

Ok i just figured it out, the Variant contains an integer, so one should use:

```
config["listname"].get_int();
```

And then do the rest in the code (according to values order in settings.ini)